# Rendering Pagination part of JSON XMLHttpRequest to HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to render pagination part of JSON data coming with XHR into HTML.

So next & previous page buttons and input for choosing the number of the desired page to jump should work without reloading.

How can I achieve it?

I tried to write a getData function in order to send the page number information through button click of next/prev buttons in pagination. Then I didn't figure out how to end this logic.

The JSON (I deleted some repetitive parts to make it short):

```
{
"results": [
{
"title": "aaa",
"tags": [
"destinations",
"rankings"
],
"main_img": "Screen_Shot_2020-07-26_at_5.55.26_PM.png",
"content": "<p>aaa</p>",
"read_time": 3,
"last_updated": "2020-07-30",
"slug": "aaa"
},
{
"title": "United States",
"tags": [
"destinations"
],
"main_img": "dmitry.jpg",
"content": "<p>aa</p>",
"read_time": 9,
"last_updated": "2020-07-30",
"slug": "united-states"
},
{
"title": "calculation methods",
"tags": [
"Others"
],
"main_img": "example2_njW98do.jpg",
"content": "<p>Yes.</p>",
"read_time": null,
"last_updated": "2020-07-16",
"slug": "calculation-methods"
},
],
"total_records": 8,
"total_pages": 2,
"page": 1,
"has_next": true,
"has_prev": false
}
```

My current code (I doubted the logic of the code, so I stopped to seek help here):

```
  <script>

     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     function getData(page_number) {
     
     xhr.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/search/' + '?page=' + page_number);
     xhr.responseType = 'json';
     }
     getData(1);
     xhr.onload = () => {
        const data = xhr.response;
        if (data.has_next == true) {
           const next_page = data.page + 1
           html_next_page = `<div class="hover-shadow btn btn-primary rounded-circle mx-1 text-center" style="padding:inherit; width: 45px; height: 45px; font-size: 30px; line-height: 40px;" id="btn-next-page">&#8250;</div>`
        }
        if (data.has_prev == true) {
           let prev_page = data.page - 1
           html_prev_page = `<div class="hover-shadow btn btn-primary rounded-circle mx-1 text-center" style="padding:inherit; width: 45px; height: 45px; font-size: 30px; line-height: 40px;">&#8249;</div>`
        }
        const cards = data.results.map(article => {
           return `
              <div class="col-12">
                 <div class="card hover-md-shadow position-relative mb-4 border-0">
                    <div class="row no-gutters px-md-3 py-3 py-lg-4">
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="my-4-3-img-wrapper h-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center" style="padding-bottom: 56.2%;">
                             <img src="/media/${article.main_img}" class="rounded-lg" alt="...">
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-8 pl-lg-2 position-static">
                          <div class="card-body px-1 px-md-4 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-around">
                             <a class="stretched-link" href="${article.slug}">
                                <h2 class="card-title text-truncate">${article.title}</h2>
                             </a>
                             <p class="card-text text-muted my-2line-ellipsis">
                                ${article.content}
                             </p>
                             <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">${article.read_time}</small></p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           `;
            }).join("")
        document.getElementById('js-card').innerHTML = cards + html_next_page
        document.getElementById("btn-next-page").addEventListener("click", function(){
           const a = getData(2);
           xhr.onload = () => {
              const data = xhr.response;
           };
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
        });
     };
     xhr.send();

  </script>
```

Comment: You should really look into using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API since `xhr` is very old and deprecated

Comment: @frozen I use fetch as well. But in my case it doesn't matter if data is pulled with fetch or XHR. It is no problem for me if you use fetch in your answer.

Comment: You can put `html_next_page` value as custom attribute in your next-button i.e : `data-value="+html_next_page+"` and when next button is clicked get that attribute and pass in your `getData()` function .